# How much time passed between the first episode Enterprise and the last episode of Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise

What is the time difference roughly in years from the first episode of *Enterprise* to the last episode of *Voyager*?

The reason I ask this is to see if it may be possible for the Discovery to encounter Borg and have no recollection of it due to having a fragmented memory of the past.
In short I am looking at my chances to see some early Borg on *Discovery*.

Answer (score 8):

The first episode of *Enterprise* is set in 2151.

The last episode of *Voyager* is set in 2377.

This is a space of 226 years.

Dates sourced [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Star_Trek).

However, none of this affects Discovery in any way.  They could jump with their spore drive to the Delta quadrant, and find the home of the Borg.  With much hand waving and plot devices, there would be no need of the Borg at that time to learn that the Discovery is from the Alpha Quadrant, etc.

So there is every chance they could be used in *Discovery*, although probably not this season.

Personally, I wouldn't want to see it though.  I think we've had enough Borg for now.  Also, their appearance in Enterprise was silly; shoehorned in for no reason.

Comment: TNG had the Borg already headed for Federation space for no apparent reason, the ENT episodes gave a reason in the last line or two of the episode

Comment: Yeah to be fair there was a good reason - it wrapped up the aftermath of First Contact, and it set up TNG, initiating the causality loop. Pretty elegant I'd say!

Answer (score 3):

### 283 years / 227 years, depending on whether you count the framing stories.

[ENT: Broken Bow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broken_Bow_(episode)) is set in 2151 (with a brief interlude to 2121)

> "Enterprise starlog, Captain Jonathan Archer – **April 16, 2151.** We've
>   been tracking the Suliban ship for ten hours, thanks to our… science
>   officer, who came up with a way to tweak the sensors.

[VOY: Endgame](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode)) is set in the year 2378 (with a brief interlude to 2404)

> **PARIS:** *It took you **thirty three years** to come up with Joe?*

---

As to the question of whether the Borg can make an appearance in Discovery, the short answer is that *anything's possible with a drive that allows instantaneous travel*, but their appearance in Borg Space would have made humanity Target #1 for the Borg rather than just another species to explore and conquer. It seems unlikely that the producers would write themselves into that corner.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as there's no accepted answer, I'll take a crack at this. Information is sourced from IMDB and Wikipedia.

The last episode of *Voyager* aired on May 23, 2001.

The first episode of *Enterprise* aired on September 26, 2001.

Therefore, the rough time difference in years between the two episodes is .34 years. :D

*(Sorry, I couldn't resist.)*

Comment: OK, gotta give credit for a perfectly valid interpretation of the question...

Comment: Thank you. I stumbled into this question and was sort of surprised nobody had beaten me to it. :D   (I'll stop being silly now.)